# I can't load datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

When I want to load data tables or give me `$` is not defined or dataTables is not a function
Can someone please help me to solve this problem? I put `<link>` with CSS data tables in the header, my `js` file with function and data tables include at the end of body

These functions deal with data table filling

```
function loadItems() {
    $.noConflict();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://localhost:44378/api/getAllAccounts",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: mySuccHandler

    });
}
function mySuccHandler(data) {
    jQuery.noConflict();
    try {

        $('#table_id').DataTable({
            "aaData": data,
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                    "mData": "userId"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "userName"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "password"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "email"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "CNP"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "firstName"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "lastName"
                },

                {
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<button onclick="">Click me</button>';
                    }
                }


            ]

        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }

}
```

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Startmin - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../css/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="../css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../css/startmin.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="../css/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Startmin</a>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left navbar-top-links">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Website</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-right navbar-top-links">

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><i class="username"></i> <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">

                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html" class="active"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> SINU</a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-male fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">
                                            <div class="studenti"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>users</div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-green">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">
                                            <div class="specializari"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>Specializari</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">124</div>
                                        <div>New Orders!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-red">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                                        <i class="fa fa-support fa-5x"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                        <div class="huge">13</div>
                                        <div>Support Tickets!</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div class="panel-footer">
                                    <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                    <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>

                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <!-- AICI II PRIMUL CHENAR DEPE INDEX-->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.panel-heading -->


                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>



    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/startmin.js"></script>
    <!-- MY JS FILE -->
    <script src="../js/functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>



    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/metisMenu.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../js/startmin.js"></script>

</body>
</html>`
```

[Screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2b29B.png)

Comment: Improve formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), `$` variable will not be defined.

1. Replace all uses of `$` with `jQuery`, for example:

   ```
   jQuery('#table_id').DataTable({
      // ... skipped ...
   });
   ```
2. Call jQuery.noConflict() only once, for example:

   ```
   <script src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
   ```